# Annotations are not allowed here проблема с android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

Для реализации функции логина в приложении я использую интерфейс как составляющую и я хочу прописать хедер и метод post но при написании @POST или @HEADERS у меня подчеркивает красным и пишет сообщение что аннотации тут не разрешены, я уже создавал новый проект, чистил его, делал rebuild чистил кеш но ничего не помогает. Если у кого-то была такая-же проблема и он ее решил буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: 1. Откройте (найдите в сети) пример с анотациями в андроид - посмотрите как записываются. 2. Опубликуйте фрагмент кода где у вас возникла ошибка, тогда можно будет показать где допущена ошибка (так что б было видно подключеные библиотеки, функцию, обьявление и другие части кода важные для этого вопроса).

Comment: я ничего не понял(((( какой пример с анотациями?? где взять фрагмент?? у меня вообще просто ни с того ни с сего начало подчеркивать красным, может просто я что то упускаю из виду?

Comment: это что-то студия тупила))))))) вставил сразу весь код отдельной набранный и ничего не подчеркивает, сорян что побеспокоил.