# Annotations are not allowed here не смог решить проблему android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, аннотации

У меня опять возникает проблема с работой android studio, я начинаю работать с room и для работы с бд мне нужно создать класс с полями, насколько я правильно понял туториал не знаю, не судите строго)) и вот я создаю класс:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public class Information {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
}
```

И вот я создал класс, куда сразу вставил эти строки, почему-то у меня они подчеркиваются красным хотя все библиотеки подключены и должно все быть в порядке `@NonNull @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id")`.

У меня был уже подобный вопрос [Annotations are not allowed here проблема с android studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853092/annotations-are-not-allowed-here-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-android-studio), где у меня студия каким-то странным образом приняла код и все было нормально но в этот раз я перепробовал все возможные способы решения и у меня ничего не получилось.

Comment: Аннотациями помечаются поля, классы, методы, параметры, следующие за ними - у Вас они болтаются сами по себе.

Comment: Вам точно не хватает `@Entity(tableName = "name_bd")
public class Information {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
}` где **name_bd** это имя базы данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо добавить само поле которое вы аннотируете чтобы оно создалось в базе как колонка (собственно к этому полю и будут применяться аннотации public int id;).

```
 public class Information {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public int id;
}
```